# What is the best ruby api to git?

Tags: ruby, git, api, windows-7

I would like to implement a Rake task that automates some of the tasks I have to do to move my changes from development to production (and yes, I know there is something out like Capistrano, and it is way too much for me). In the center, there are some interactive commands like `git add -i` and a series of commit and push. On the production side, there will be pulls and assets tasks to do.

It is tedious to type in all the time the same commands so I would like to automate it completely. What I have not found is *the* Ruby API for Git.

It should work under Windows 7, and allow at least the following commands: `git add`, `git status`, `git commit`, `git push`, `git pull`.

Comment: If capistrano is too much, have you thought of using rake instead?

Comment: Well, that I have asked for in the question: I would like to implement a Rake task ... So the piece I am missing is a reasonable Git API for Ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This one](https://rubygems.org/gems/git) seems to be quite popular. If you are more interested in GitHub then you might want to look at [this one](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-api-client).

UPDATE:

[Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) seems to be the newest one out there though the [Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/rugged) for it has not been built in a while. Might be best to use the source from Github.

Comment: But it is pretty old (2.5 years no changes at all). What is your experience with it. Is the API reasonable, have you used it under Windows?

Comment: Sorry, take a look at my update. I have not used any of them so it would be hard to answer the reasonableness comment.

Comment: After some experiments, [Git](https://rubygems.org/gems/git) seems reasonable: it works in my `rails c` console, and has the features that I want.

Answer (score 10):

I know, bad habit, but I would like to document the experiences of this weekend:

- There is a similar question on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62843/best-ruby-git-library that names the 3 relevant candidates: [Git](http://rubygems.org/gems/git), [Grit](http://rubygems.org/gems/grit) and [Rugged](http://rubygems.org/gems/rugged).
- Git and Grit are not developed further, Rugged is currently developed, but not finished.
- Git works out of the box, but has some deficiencies:

  - There are known shortcomings (see the [issues](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git/issues?state=open)).
  - I had the problem, that added and changed items are not well matched, they can be in only one of the 2 states (which is not true for Git currently).
  - The API is reasonable, and works well in console, Ruby script or Rake task.
- Grit did not work for me at all, and I did not found the reason. I got stack traces (low level ones), and tried a few patches that could be relevant for usage under Windows 7, but with no success.
- Rugged is not installable for me, so I [filed a bug](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged/issues/43) to rugged which got some feedback. The problem seems to be that rugged only works for POSIX systems, so it is not compilable with DevKit for Ruby.

So I will try to find a compiled version of `libgit2.dll` for Windows 7, and will try to use that. I have done that in the  past with `sqlite3.dll`, so perhaps that is the best try. For me, rugged is the most sensible solution, because there are people behind that project, they are interested to provide a solution that works cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

July 2013 update:

It looks like [Rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) is the tool of choice at the moment. It is being actively maintained and it looks like most (all) of the core committers work at github.

Even though [grit](https://github.com/mojombo/grit) is the most popular, and is created by one of the github founders, it hasn't been touched for 5 months and has had little activity.

See [Ruby-Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/git_Tools) for details.